# Dynamic data filter using InputField

Tags: inputfield

I would like to filter data in the table dynamically.
Here is the example of the code:

```
search = "da";
data = {Range[100],ResourceFunction["RandomString"][{"a", "d", "e", "n", "r", "s"}, {100, 5}]} // Transpose;
Column@{
   InputField[Dynamic@search, String],
   Dynamic@search,
   Cases[data, {_, x_} /; StringContainsQ[x, search]] // TableView
 }
```

Its dynamically updates 'search' variable on the change of InputField, but not when I apply Cases filter. When I put 'Dynamic@search instead' of 'search' inside of 'StringContainsQ' it return the error message "Element da is not a valid string or pattern element in da".
I will be appreciated if somebody could help me to solve the issue.

Comment: `Cases` doesn't know how to handle dynamic variables. You have to wrap `Dynamic` around the entire `TableView` to make it work, e.g. `Column@{InputField[Dynamic@search, String], Dynamic@search, 
  Cases[data, {_, x_} /; StringContainsQ[x, search]] // TableView // Dynamic}`. This way, the entire view will be recreated every time `search` changes

Comment: Try `Dynamic` with the `Column`: `Dynamic@Column@{
   InputField[Dynamic@search, String]
   , search
   , TableView[Cases[data, {_, x_} /; StringContainsQ[x, search]]]
   }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
search = "da";
SeedRandom[1];
data = {Range[100], 
    ResourceFunction["RandomString"][{"a", "d", "e", "n", "r", 
      "s"}, {100, 5}]} // Transpose;
Column@{InputField[Dynamic[search], String], Dynamic@search, 
    Cases[data, {_, x_} /; StringContainsQ[x, search]] // TableView //
      Dynamic} // Print;
```

[image]

and with a different input of "aa":

[image]